# Analysis using eigen functions of the problem $x^2y''+2xy'+\lambda y=0,\ \ x\in[1, \ 2],\ \ y(1)=y(2)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the BVP $$x^2y''+2xy'+\lambda y=0,\ \ x\in[1, \ 2],\ \ y(1)=y(2)=0.$$ Then prove or disprove the statement:

For any continuous function $f:[1,\ 2]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\neq0$, for some $x\in[1,\ 2],$ there exists a solution $y$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{1}^{2}fydx\neq0$.

I got non-trivial solutions (eigen functions) as $y_n(x)=x^{\frac{-1}{2}} \sin(\frac{n \pi}{\ln 2} \ln x)$ only for $\lambda > 1/4$. If $f$ were positive, we could have solutions since $\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} \leq 1$ for $x \in [1,2]$, but I cannot confirm about such a general continuous function $f$.